# facebook redirect_uri redirecting to local domain instead of staying on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My facebook application will not stay on facebook after the request permissions dialog has been shown. It keeps redirecting to the redirect_uri (State the obvious), but my question is how can i get the application to run in facebook iframe?

I have tried setting the redirect_uri to https://apps.facebook.com/myApp but that is not allowed it shows an error?

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

My current Code

```
<?php
require 'facebook/facebook.php';

// Get User ID
$facebook_config = array(
  'appId'  => '8**************3',
  'secret' => '5*************************d',
  'cookie'  =>  true
);

$facebook = new Facebook($facebook_config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'redirect_uri' => 'localhost';
  'scope'   =>  'user_location'
));

$logout_url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

if($user)
{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    header("Content-Type:text/plain");
    print_R($user_profile);
    die();
}
else if(!$user)
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this line: `'redirect_uri' => 'localhost';`

Since, after login if nothing is mentioned in `redirect_uri`, it will redirect to the same page automatically.

In case you want to proceed to some other page, say `success.php`, you should give the `redirect_uri` wrt the canvas url i.e. the actual url of this page, not http://apps.facebook.......

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but when `'redirect_uri' => 'localhost';` is removed it still redirects to localhost and gets stuck.

I did a quick fix that did a redirection back to facebook

```
$token = $_GET['code'];
if ($token) { ?>
<form action="https://apps.facebook.com/MyApp/" method="post" name='frm'>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token?>">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

That redirected everything back to facebook and would work, but as you said here

> In case you want to proceed to some other page, say success.php, you should give the redirect_uri wrt the canvas url i.e. the actual url of this page, not http://apps.facebook.......

i changed my redirect_uri from `localhost` to `https://apps.facebook.com/MyApp/index.php` and everything worked smoothly,